# How to find significancy of grouped Data

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a result of my pre-grouping of grouping columns like this

| Letters | Numbers |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |

Now what I wanna do is, to define that C is a Significant factor for 1s as its 100% there but with A or B its only 33%. I wanna show that C significantly differs from A and B.

I think there should be a solution with pandas and data frames, but I'm not really sure how to find that value. Which of the pandas Methods can I use to find that value?

Expected Output:
C significantly differs from A and B in its result spectrum. This is proven by this factor of significancy (this factor is what i search)

Thanks for the help in advance :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by playing more with my data.
The answer is to build a new dataframe with 6 columns

| A | B | C | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | - | 1 | - | - |
| 1 | - | - | - | 1 | - |
| 1 | - | - | - | - | 1 |
| - | 1 | - | 1 | - | - |
| - | 1 | - | - | 1 | - |
| - | 1 | - | - | - | 1 |
| - | - | 1 | 1 | - | - |
| - | - | 1 | 1 | - | - |
| - | - | 1 | 1 | - | - |

That way I can use the corr function of pandas and see how significant my "C" actually really is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the number of 1's in the groups by checking [`.eq(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and then group by `Letters` and use [`.GroupBy.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to get the count of 1's.  Then, divide by the group size by using [`.GroupBy.size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), as follows:

```
df['Numbers'].eq(1).groupby(df['Letters']).sum() / df.groupby(df['Letters']).size()
```

**Result:**

```
Letters
A    0.333333
B    0.333333
C    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Well this defines that its 33% vs 100% but its not calculating any significancy of that factor.

Comment: @Giga  Please show your expected output in the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for that idea, i edit my question with an expected output. Hopefully its understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
number = 1
df.groupby('Letters')['Numbers'].value_counts(normalize=True).loc[(slice(None),number)]
```

Comment: Well this defines that its 33% vs 100% but its not calculating any significancy of that factor.
I want to show that its not only an accident that this happened. That C significantly differes from A and B